# Live Stream IP Cameras within Office

Tags: camera, rtsp, p2p, rtmp, live-streaming

I want to live stream multiple ip cameras ( 20 +)  in my office  to a url/obs/vlc etc  . IP cameras support rtgs and p2p protocol . I want on premise solution as cloud is not recommended.

I was exploring Nginx RTMP server but not sure how to move ahead further and whether it is the best choice ..